# MLP on Iris Data not working but it does fine on MNIST - Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

So I'm a little bit baffled. I have just started working with the Keras framework for Python (which is awesome by the way!).

However just trying a few simple test of neural networks has got me a bit confused. I initially tried to classify the Iris data as it was a small, quick and simple dataset. However when I constructed a neural network for it (4 input dimensions, 8 node hidden layer, 3 node output layer for binary classification of the 3 classes). This however didn't produce any predictive powers at all (100 samples in the training set, a separate 50 in the test set. Both had been shuffled so as to include a good distribution of classes in each).

Now I thought I was doing something wrong, but I thought I'd give the network a quick test on the MNIST dataset just in case. So I used basically the exact same network (other than changing the input dimensions to 784, hidden nodes to 30, and output nodes to 10 for the binary encoded 0-9 output). And this worked perfectly! With a 97% accuracy rate and a 5% loss.

So now I'm not sure why the Iris dataset isn't playing ball, does anyone have any clues? I've tried changing the number of hidden layer nodes and also normalized the X input.

Here's an output I've produced when I've manually run some of the test set through the trained Iris model. As you can see it's basically producing a uniform random guess.

```
Target: [ 1.  0.  0.]  | Predicted: [[ 0.44635904  0.43874186  0.45729554]]
Target: [ 0.  0.  1.]  | Predicted: [[ 0.44618103  0.43869928  0.45735642]]
Target: [ 0.  1.  0.]  | Predicted: [[ 0.44612524  0.43863046  0.45729461]]
Target: [ 0.  0.  1.]  | Predicted: [[ 0.44617626  0.43870446  0.45736298]]
Target: [ 0.  0.  1.]  | Predicted: [[ 0.44613886  0.43865535  0.45731983]]
```

And here's my full code for the Iris MLP (the MNIST one is essentially the same)

```
import numpy as np
import random
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import preprocessing

# Model Layers Defnition
# Input layer (12 neurons), Output layer (1 neuron)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(3, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Iris has 150 samples, each sample has 4 dimensions
iris = load_iris()
iris_xy = zip(iris.data, iris.target)
random.shuffle(iris_xy) # Iris data is sequential in it's labels
iris_x, iris_y = zip(*iris_xy)
iris_x = preprocessing.normalize(np.array(iris_x))
iris_y = np.array(iris_y)

# Encode decimal numbers to array
iris_y_enc = np.zeros(shape=(len(iris_y),3))
for i, y in enumerate(iris_y):
    iris_y_enc[i][y] = 1

train_data = np.array(iris_x[:100]) # 100 samples for training
test_data  = np.array(iris_x[100:]) # 50 samples for testing
train_targets = np.array(iris_y_enc[:100])
test_targets  = np.array(iris_y_enc[100:])

model.fit(train_data, train_targets, nb_epoch=10)

#score = model.evaluate(test_data, test_targets)

for test in zip(test_data, test_targets):
    prediction = model.predict(np.array(test[0:1]))
    print "Target:", test[1], " | Predicted:", prediction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default [sklearn.preprocessing.normalize](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) normalizes samples, not features. Replace sklearn.preprocessing.normalize with [sklearn.preprocessing.scale](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html). This will center and scale (to unit variance) every feature.

Also give it more than 10 epochs. Here are learning curves (log loss) for 5000 epochs:

[image: Learning Curves]

This should end up with an accuracy of about 96%.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done it. Especially the larger number of epochs. I had just assumed that because the MNIST dataset converges to a high degree of accuracy on a small number of epochs (98%+ in 3 epochs!) that the Iris dataset, being simpler would also have such quick convergence